# How can I prevent my frames of animation from drawing over top one another?

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I am building a live wallpaper app that performs frame-by-frame animation. When I test the app my animation appears on the screen, but the frames don't always clear before a new frame is drawn.

I intend for the animation to draw forward to the last frame and then backward to the first frame. Sometimes, though, the animation appears to draw forward or backward one or two frames before continuing in the proper sequence.

I load the resource IDs to my images this way:

```
private int[] res_id = {R.drawable.flag_1, R.drawable.flag_2, R.drawable.flag_3, R.drawable.flag_4, R.drawable.flag_5, 
                    R.drawable.flag_6, R.drawable.flag_7, R.drawable.flag_8, R.drawable.flag_9, R.drawable.flag_10, 
                    R.drawable.flag_11, R.drawable.flag_12, R.drawable.flag_13, R.drawable.flag_14, R.drawable.flag_15, 
                    R.drawable.flag_16, R.drawable.flag_17, R.drawable.flag_18, R.drawable.flag_19, R.drawable.flag_20, 
                    R.drawable.flag_21, R.drawable.flag_22, R.drawable.flag_23, R.drawable.flag_24, R.drawable.flag_25, 
                    R.drawable.flag_26, R.drawable.flag_27, R.drawable.flag_28, R.drawable.flag_29, R.drawable.flag_30};
```

I cycle through the images and draw them like this:

```
void drawFlag(Canvas cFlagCanvas) 
    {           
        Bitmap bFlagFrame;
        long time = 0;

        if(bStartPlaying == true)
        {
            iFrameCount = 0;
            bStartPlaying = false;
            bIsPlaying = true;

            //Load the first frame, decode it, and scale it to the screen.
            bLenguaFrame = decodeLLResource(mContext.getResources(), res_id[iFrameCount], 400, 300);

            cFlagCanvas.drawBitmap(bFlagFrame, iCenterX, iCenterY, null);

            last_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
            iFrameCount++;

            bLastFrame = bFlagFrame;                
            bFlagFrame.recycle();               
        }
        else if (bIsPlaying == true)
        {
            if(iFrameCount == 0 || iFrameCount == 29)
            {
                iDelay = FirstLastDelay; //set to 2000 milli-seconds
            }
            else
            {
               iDelay = TweenDelay; //set to 120 milli-seconds
            }

            try
            {
                bFlagFrame = decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), res_id[iFrameCount], 400, 300);

                time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - last_tick);                    

                //Draw the next frame only if the delay time has passed.
                if (time >= iDelay) 
                {
                    cFlagCanvas.drawBitmap(bFlagFrame, iCenterX, iCenterY, null);

                    last_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    bLastFrame = bFlagFrame;                
                    bFlagFrame.recycle();

                    //Adjust the frame count
                    if(bPlayingForward == true)
                    {
                        if(iFrameCount < 29)
                        {
                            iFrameCount++;
                            bPlayingForward = true;
                        }
                        else if(iFrameCount == 29)
                        {
                            iFrameCount--;
                            bPlayingForward = false;
                        }               
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(iFrameCount > 0)
                        {
                            iFrameCount--;
                            bPlayingForward = false;
                        }
                        else if(iFrameCount == 0)
                        {
                            iFrameCount++;
                            bPlayingForward = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Delay not expired. Redraw the last frame.
                else 
                {    
                    cFlagCanvas.drawBitmap(bLastFrame, iCenterX, iCenterY, null);

                }                   

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }                                      
    }
```

What I get is an animation that loads and plays without taxing my memory. However, older images don't clear from the screen before new images are drawn. How can I ensure that the canvas displays only one frame at a time?

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Canvas.drawColor() to clear the canvas with whatever color you want before you draw each frame (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawColor(int))

Comment: Thanks, Neiti01. I tried calling Canvas.drawColor() before calling Canvas.drawBitmap(), but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or describe what you're seeing? Also try using drawColor() with red or something to see if it's working at all

Comment: Hello, Neiti01. I tried drawing red, blue, and green at different places in my drawFlag function but those colors never displayed. After some more research I found a line that DOES clear the canvas between images. I just don't know why it works. The line is  -- canvas.drawColor(color.black, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); --